# How to change the name of an observation according to its occurrence

Tags: r

I have patients who have diagnoses and each patient is represented by an `ID` (I have three one here). Some diagnoses occur recurrently, if this is the case I would like to add the number of the recurrence in front of the diagnosis.
For example for the patient `ID=2`, the second occurrence of `"SLE"` will be rename in `"SLE2"` and the third occurrence would be renamed in `"SLE3"`

```
ID<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,5))
time<-c(1:10,1:10,1:5)
diag<-c("ANN",NA,NA,NA,"SLE","ANN",NA,NA,NA,NA,
        "SLE",NA,NA,NA,"SLE","BPG","SLE",NA,NA,NA,"SLE",NA,NA,"ANN",NA)

mydata<-data.frame(ID,time,diag)
```

My new variable must be like this:

```
   ID time diag diag2
1   1    1  ANN   ANN
2   1    2 <NA>  <NA>
3   1    3 <NA>  <NA>
4   1    4 <NA>  <NA>
5   1    5  SLE   SLE
6   1    6  ANN  ANN2
7   1    7 <NA>  <NA>
8   1    8 <NA>  <NA>
9   1    9 <NA>  <NA>
10  1   10 <NA>  <NA>
11  2    1  SLE   SLE
12  2    2 <NA>  <NA>
13  2    3 <NA>  <NA>
14  2    4 <NA>  <NA>
15  2    5  SLE  SLE2
16  2    6  BPG   BPG
17  2    7  SLE  SLE3
18  2    8 <NA>  <NA>
19  2    9 <NA>  <NA>
20  2   10 <NA>  <NA>
21  3    1  SLE   SLE
22  3    2 <NA>  <NA>
23  3    3 <NA>  <NA>
24  3    4  ANN   ANN
25  3    5 <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is using both the `stringr` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(stringr)

new_tbl %>%
group_by(ID, diag) %>%
mutate(diag2 = if_else(is.na(diag),diag, 
                       paste0(diag,cumsum(str_detect(diag, diag)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to make use of `dense_rank` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(ID, diag) %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(time)) %>%
  mutate(diag2 = case_when(is.na(diag) ~ diag,
                           rank == 1 ~ diag,                               
                           TRUE ~ paste0(diag, rank))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `make.unique`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[!is.na(diag), diag2 := make.unique(diag, sep = ""), ID]
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. The script is interesting but does not take into account of grouping by ID. I will try to group by ID.

Comment: @SeydouGORO sorry, my mistake.  I meant the `by=`, but somehow didn't use it